# How to mark as non constructive a post with so many votes?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I was looking at this post [Are getters and setters poor design? Contradictory advice seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-evil) and I saw it was closed  as non constructive.

It has so many votes and it discusses a serious issue. What is the point of having stackoverflow-post rules if they lead to this kind of thing?

How can you even close a post with so many votes?

Is it possible to reopen?

Comment: votes != constructivity of a question. Also this is an old question, that was written when the site standards were not as strict

Comment: What's the point of keeping that question open? It won't really benefit from further answers. What will the community gain by re-opening it?

Comment: "What are your opinions on this?"  Stack Exchange is not about *opinions*, it's about *answers*.  I think it would be difficult to say whether or not any programming construct has a moral leaning such as "evil".

Comment: @casperOne Monads are evil.

Comment: @Yannis you must be just trolling around... how about, i want to investigate what are my options regarding a disputable issue

Comment: @Hugo Dozois i might actually understand that, although do not totally agree that it should be closed... but the number of votes does not raise any issue in the back of your head?

Comment: The fact that is being closed does not affect anything at all. It still possible to read the answer. Just not possible to answer anymore

Answer (score 7):

It is an opinion question. That does not fit for Stack Overflow. Just because people have voted it up doesn't mean it shouldn't be closed.

And yes, there is a way to reopen it. However, this will not happen. The question simply does not fit our Q&A style.

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Furthermore, it was probably upvoted *before* the site standards became stricter. In the beginning of SO, questions like these were accepted more. Now, they are not constructive.

Comment: so what is wrong with an opinion question? mark it as opinion question then, and leave it be, not close it (don't have such a thing? make it). 
what if the issue at hand is really "disputable" and you want to see opinions? stack overflow is a very good place to get "opinions" from good technical people...

Comment: (i mean, you did not even move it to that programmer exchange, or what is called, stack overflow version for general programming concepts, or the more philosophical  version of stack overflow). it all looks like you are hiding behind some rules  to do evil. it is an important issue, it involves lots of discussion, IT HAS MANY VOTES, it is debatable and i might want to actually hear opinions about it (i want to investigate on my options regarding the issue).

Comment: @Belun Neither Stack Overflow nor Programmers are good places to get opinions or have open ended discussions. If you have _specific_ questions, we'll be happy to help, but for everything else you might want to look elsewhere.

Comment: @Belun `so what is wrong with an opinion question?` They don't fit the guidelines of Stack Overflow and are not constructive. They don't have one definite answer. `mark it as opinion question then` ...that would be closing it. `(don't have such a thing? make it).` Why? Opinion questions don't fit for SO! `what if the issue at hand is really "disputable" and you want to see opinions?` Then Stack Overflow is not the right place for you.`stack overflow is a very good place to get "opinions" from good technical people` No, it is the worst place to do this; your question will be closed immediately.

Answer (score 4):

The [question asks for opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/565095/458741):

> What are your opinions on this?

and [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565227/458741) makes clear this is opinion:

> There is also the point of view that most of the time...

Lastly, [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/565117/458741) makes clear that there is no, one, answer:

> It really depends on the situation though - sometimes you really do just want a dumb data object.

The close reason describes why this has been closed (my emphasis):

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be **supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion**. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

The question has been closed as not constructive because it is asking for opinions, and it got them.